# Django Rest Framework - query params with special characters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my model is:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField()
```

my viewset:

```
class SkillViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Skill.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SkillSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter )
    search_fields = ('id', 'skill')
    ordering_fields = '__all__'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = property_models.Skill.objects.all()
        skill = self.request.query_params.get('skill', None)
        if skill is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(skill__icontains=skill)
        return queryset
```

One of my languages is "C++"

This works:

```
Skill.objects.filter(skill__icontains='C++')
```

However calling my api does not work:

```
/skills/?skill=c++
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have to URL encode your parameters so `c++` becomes `c%2B%2B` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Just did not know what to google for :-) Thanks! Will accept answer once SO allows for it!